# Do an ambiguous grammar and its corresponding unambiguous version generate the same language?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

If I have an ambiguous grammar G and its disambiguated version D.
Then which one is true  **L(D) ⊂ L(G)** , **L(G) ⊂ L(D)** or **L(G)=L(D)**?

As I tried with some examples to transform a grammar to it unambiguous version but i found that both are equivalent.

I mean is there a specific set relation between both. Please help me and provide an example if possible.

Comment: The semantics of "its X-version" give the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you disambiguate a grammar, you usually want at least to keep the language the same. So the answer is that you want  $\mathcal L(G)=\mathcal L(D)$.

If you accepted that $\mathcal L(G)\subset \mathcal L(D)$ then you could simply choose $\mathcal L(D)=\Sigma^*$, since $\Sigma^*$ has an unambiguous grammar. Of course $\Sigma$ is the terminal alphabet.

If you accepted that $\mathcal L(D)\subset \mathcal L(G)$ then you could simply choose $\mathcal L(D)=\emptyset$ since $\emptyset$ has an unambiguous grammar.

I assume you were considering context-free (CF) languages. You should have said so.

And you should remember some facts that will not help:

- Some CF languages are inherently ambiguous, so that you cannot find an unambiguous grammar for them. Furthermore, it is [undecidable whether a CF language is inherently ambiguous](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19102/ambiguity-in-regular-and-context-free-languages/19116#19116),
- It is  undecidable to know whether a grammar is ambiguous, hence it is not clear when a disambiguating transformation is needed.

See also [wikipedia page on ambiguous grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar).

Comment: Kkk..It means it depends how close unambiguous grammar equivalent to my ambiguous grammar i can find for my need. right?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. First what is "Kkk". An
unambiguous grammar D giving the same language as an ambiguous one G
may be extremely different: it will produce very different parse
trees, though the language is the same, where just strings are concerned.  What meaning do you give to one grammar being close to
another. Maybe, if you stated your purpose and "your need", I might
have a better chance at giving you a proper and useful answer.

Comment: I mean producing the same set of strings which i intended to produce using my ambiguous version.

Comment: @monkey As I said, producing the same set of strings is the minimum you
normally require. Getting "similar" parse-tree is not something that
you easily get. But I do not understand what is you practical problem
with ambiguity, and why you are interested in finding an unambiguous
grammar D equivalent to your ambiguous one, i.e. producing the same strings.

Comment: ad last paragraph: disambiguating is not computable since ambiguity is undecidable.

Comment: @Raphael I agree, though I am always wary of such statements, since though true in general, there could be families of cases where it works well ... I do not mean this specific problem, but undecidability statements in general,

Comment: @Raphael Can't we have a set such that property P is undecidable for elements
of S, and an equivalence relation E, such that, for every s∈S, there is
a computable s'∈S such that (s,s')∈E and P(s'). What I mean is, though
there is a good chance for difficulty, I am not sure your statement is
so obvious. But I may have missed a point.

Comment: If I'm not missing something, you just outlined how to prove by reduction (E) why disambiguating is uncomputable. If it was, you could apply the method and check if the grammar changed; the original was ambiguous iff the output is different. (Oh yes, there's a gap: what if unambiguous grammars change, too? The method may not have to "realize" whether the input is ambiguous, it may just change things that remove ambiguity, if any. Is that what you meant?)

Comment: @Raphael Yes, that is what I meant. I was trying to sketch a proof for what you said, and realized the algorithm could also modify unambiguous grammars. Now that does not mean that you are wrong to suspect it is not computable. You are probably right.